# Find if current time is between a range

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

I can find how to get if a date is between a range, but I cant seem how to create a date at a specific time.

What would be the simplest way to see if [NSDate date] is between a time range?

I want to display a personalized greeting like the following:

> 12 pm - 4:59:9999 pm @"Good afternoon, foo"
>   5 pm - 11:59:9999 pm @"Good evening, foo"
>   12 am - 11:59:9999 am @"Good morning, foo"

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes you can using [`NSDateComponents`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which will return the hour in the 24 hour format.

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];

if(hour >= 0 && hour < 12)
    NSLog(@"Good morning, foo");
else if(hour >= 12 && hour < 17)
    NSLog(@"Good afternoon, foo");
else if(hour >= 17)
    NSLog(@"Good evening, foo");
```

**Swift 3**

```
let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())

if hour >= 0 && hour < 12 {
    print("Good Morning")
} else if hour >= 12 && hour < 17 {
    print("Good Afternoon")
} else if hour >= 17 {
    print("Good Evening")
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately i am out of votes for today. Nice Answer though.

Comment: As of iOS8 you need to use NSCalendarUnitHour but good answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated for Swift 3.0**

```
let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())

if hour >= 0 && hour < 12 {
    print("Good Morning")
} else if hour >= 12 && hour < 17 {
    print("Good Afternoon")
} else if hour >= 17 {
    print("Good Evening")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `NSCalendar` instance to create a `NSDateComponents` instance out of your `NSDate`, then just check the hours, minutes and seconds property of the `NSDateComponents` and present the appropriate message.

Answer (score 0):

**Noon** is at **12:00 PM**. **Afternoon** is from **12:01 PM** to around **5:00 PM**. **Evening** is from **5:01 PM** to **8 PM**, or around sunset. **Night** is from sunset to sunrise, so from **8:01** PM until **5:59** AM.

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];

if(hour >= 6 && hour < 12)
    NSLog(@"Good morning!");
else if(hour >= 12 && hour < 17)
    NSLog(@"Good afternoon!");
else if(hour >= 17 && hour < 20)
    NSLog(@"Good evening!");
else if((hour >= 20) || (hour >= 0 && hour < 6))
    NSLog(@"Good night!");
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just use the class `NSDate` to grab the time on the iPhone.

```
NSDate * today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar * cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents * comps = [cal components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

if ( [comps hour]>0 && [comps hour] < 12 )
    NSLog(@"Good morning, foo");

if ( [comps hour] > 12 && [comps hour] < 17 )
    NSLog(@"Good afternoon, foo");

if ( [comps hour] >17 && [comps hour]<24  )
    NSLog(@"Good evening, foo");
```

Reference: [NSDate Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: So whats going to happen between 12:00 pm and 12:59.9999 pm and 5 pm and 5:59.9999 pm ? :)