# (Obj-c) Identify morning, afternoon or night from a date string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working in Objective-C. I have this three values in string, which they determine the part of the day

```
NSString *morning = @"7:01";
NSString *afternoon = @"12:01"
NSString *night = @"19:01"
```

And my original date is this, also in String

```
NSString *currentTime = @"Sat, 17 Oct 2015 9:58 am CDT"
```

I need to identify if the current date is morning, afternoon or night according with the current date as String. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: parse the string as date, extract the hour component and then check that hour value against the morning/afternoon/night boundaries?! Have you tried anything by yourself yet?

Comment: An important point to add to @luk2302 comment is you need to parse the string as a date **and timezone**. Standard date-time parsing will allow for the timezone but will not report it and just return the absolute time point - which is useless to determine morning/afternoon/evening as every absolute time point is all of them!

Comment: Once you parse the date as @luk2302 recommended you can use the code in the following post to accomplish what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945553/find-if-current-time-is-between-a-range/6945653#6945653 You will need to adjust the times to what you prefer.

Comment: @Joe - that code will only work if the system timezone is the same as the one in `currentTime` (CDT in the example). This seemingly simple question is more involved than it seems, and Apple recently made it harder... I'll explain in an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has received a negative score (-4 at the time of writing) as people obviously feel you haven't shown the effort SO expects. However your question hides a gotcha and something which Apple recently made harder, which makes it interesting.

Your sample time is:

```
NSString *currentTime = @"Sat, 17 Oct 2015 9:58 am CDT"
```

which would seem to be "morning". However this is exactly the same time as:

```
Sat, 17 Oct 2015 2:58 pm GMT
```

which would seem to be "afternoon". Both these times are:

```
Sat, 17 Oct 2015 14:58 UTC
```

**Why is this an issue?**

An `NSDate` is a point in time *without* any associated  time zone. The class `NSDateFormatter`, and associated methods on `NSDate` itself, will parse a date-time string and produce the absolute UTC point in time the string represents. Any time zone in the string, such as `CDT` in the example, is allowed for in determining the absolute time point but is not directly represented in the `NSDate` value that results.

When the `NSCalendar` class is used to break out the parts of a date it does so in relation to a time zone, which defaults to the system time zone.

What all this adds up to is if your app is running, say, on a computer in the UK and you follow the suggestion in the comments:

1. parse the time (using `NSDateFormatter`)
2. break out the hour & min to get an `NSDateComponents` value (using `NSCalendar`); and
3. compare the hour & min to your boundaries then your sample time will be reported as "afternoon"

Not good :-(

What you need is to parse the date-time (getting a standard UTC time point) *and* the time zone, you can then pass that time zone to `NSCalendar` and the rest is easy.

**Apple makes it harder**

Prior to OS X 10.9 & iOS 7 the `NSDateFormatter` class returned an `NSCalendarDate` date value, that type was a subclass of `NSDate` and also stored an `NSTimeZone` value. So parsing your sample returned both the time point "Sat, 17 Oct 2015 14:58 UTC" and the time zone "UTC-5". With that information `NSCalendar` could be used to break out the hour & min and correctly determine the time is "morning".

`NSCalendarDate` is now deprecated, and while it is still possible to use it this could change at any moment. Apple do not yet appear to have provide an alternative "parse date and time zone" method.

**Parsing both the date and time zone offset**

From the simple observation that if you parse "Sat, 17 Oct 2015 9:58 am CDT" ignoring the time zone and treating it as UTC the result is an absolute time point which differs by 5 hours, the time zone offset for CDT, from the one obtained if the string is parsed taking the time zone into account you have a method to obtain the time zone - parse the string twice, once ignoring the time zone, and determine the difference.

This may not be the best algorithm, but it does work... (you may insert here warnings about premature optimisation!)

So here goes (minimal comments, look the methods up in the documentation, error checking etc. - treat as an outline only):

```
- (BOOL) dateAndZoneFromString:(NSString *)timeString // the date-time string
                    dateFormat:(NSString *)dateFormat // the format of the date-time, should contain a time zone format at the end
                    parsedDate:(NSDate **)date        // NSDate representing the absolute time point
                    parsedZone:(NSTimeZone **)zone    // NSTimeZone representing the time zone of the original string
                         error:(NSError **)error
{
   NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];

   // parse timeString taking time zone into account
   df.dateFormat = dateFormat;
   NSDate *absDate = [df dateFromString:timeString];

   // parse timeString ignoring the time zone by removing the format specifier from dateFormat
   df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
   df.dateFormat = [dateFormat stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" *[zZvV]+$" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, dateFormat.length)];

   NSDate *zonelessDate;
   NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, timeString.length);
   if ( [df getObjectValue:&zonelessDate forString:timeString range:&range error:error] )
   {
      // parse successful, calculate the difference and construct an NSTimeZone value
      NSTimeInterval offset = [zonelessDate timeIntervalSinceDate:absDate];
      NSTimeZone *timezone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:offset];
      *date = absDate;
      *zone = timezone;
      return YES;
   }
   else
      return NO;
}
```

If you pass `@"Sat, 17 Oct 2015 9:58 am CDT"` and for format `@"E, d MMM y h:m a z"` to this method it will return the time point "Sat, 17 Oct 2015 14:58 UTC" as an `NSDate` and the time zone "UTC-5" as an `NSTimeZone`.

If you pass `@"Sat, 17 Oct 2015 2:58 pm GMT"` then it will return the *same* absolute time point and a time zone of "UTC+0".

For this point you can use these values with `NSCalendar`, `NSDateComponents`, and simple comparisons to determine morning/afternoon/night.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)ShowTimeMessage
{
    // For calculating the current date
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

    // Make Date Formatter
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh a EEEE"];

    // hh for hour mm for minutes and a will show you AM or PM
    NSString *str = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    // NSLog(@"%@", str);

    // Sperate str by space i.e. you will get time and AM/PM at index 0 and 1 respectively
    NSArray *array = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    // Now you can check it by 12. If < 12 means Its morning > 12 means its evening or night

    NSString *message;
    NSString *timeInHour;
    NSString *am_pm;

    NSString *DayOfWeek;
    if (array.count>2)
    {
        // am pm case
        timeInHour = array[0];
        am_pm = array[1];
        DayOfWeek  = array[2];
    }
    else if (array.count>1)
    {
        // 24 hours case
        timeInHour = array[0];
        DayOfWeek = array[1];
    }

    if (am_pm)
    {

        if ([timeInHour integerValue]>=4 && [timeInHour integerValue]<=9 && [am_pm isEqualToString:@"AM"])
        {
            message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Morning"];
                    }
        else if (([timeInHour integerValue]>=10 && [timeInHour integerValue]!=12 && [am_pm isEqualToString:@"AM"]) || (([timeInHour integerValue]<4 || [timeInHour integerValue]==12) && [am_pm isEqualToString:@"PM"]))
        {
            message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Afternoon"];
                    }
        else if ([timeInHour integerValue]>=4 && [timeInHour integerValue]<=9 && [am_pm isEqualToString:@"PM"])
        {
            message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Evening"];

        }
        else if (([timeInHour integerValue]>=10 && [timeInHour integerValue]!=12 && [am_pm isEqualToString:@"PM"]) || (([timeInHour integerValue]<4 || [timeInHour integerValue]==12) && [am_pm isEqualToString:@"AM"]))
        {
            message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Night"];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        if ([timeInHour integerValue]>=4 && [timeInHour integerValue]<10)
        {
            message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Morning"];

        }
        else if ([timeInHour integerValue]>=10 && [timeInHour integerValue]<16)
        {
            message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Afternoon"];

        }
        else if ([timeInHour integerValue]>=16 && [timeInHour integerValue]<22)
        {
            message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Evening"];

        }
        else
        {
            message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Night"];

        }
    }

    if (DayOfWeek)
    {
        _timeLbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",DayOfWeek,message];
    }

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.